# Hide element appended to div on click?

Tags: jquery

I am appeding a div withing some of div's on a web page using the following

```
var strScript = '<div class="' + cssClass + '" > ' + message + '</div>';
var notifyElement = $(strScript);
```

Now I want to set this appended div to be **Disappeared** when users click on that **OnClick**

Can I do something like this

```
notifyElement.OnClick(function .......
```

I can't select the element by passing the id coz there will be more than one div's of this type in a single page.

Comment: It's *well worth* your time spending an hour or two reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It really only takes that long, and it pays for itself in no time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the `click` function (or `on`):

```
notifyElement.click(function() {
    notifyElement.hide();
});
```

or

```
notifyElement.on("click", function() {
    notifyElement.hide();
});
```

or if you might use the `notifyElement` variable for something else in the future:

```
notifyElement.on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: by setting this everything within `notifyElement` will trigger this event?

Comment: @HIT: Yes, the `click` event bubbles. So unless you have an element within it that handles `click` and stops propagation, the notify element will see the click.

Answer (score 1):

yep:

```
notifyElement.click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

or do it while creating:

```
$(notifyElement, {
    "click": function() {
        $(this).hide()   
    }
});
```